# Finding similar project specification using clustering algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, medicine

I have budget estimation of some bio-medical projects and their specification details.

Could anyone suggest how to do clustering algorithm to find the similar kind of specification. Which clustering will be best for this situation? My aim is to find the nearest specification to estimate the cost efficiently. When a new specification will come my duty is to give them the very similar specification details from the past so that they can easily estimate how many patient need to screened, how many approx call may need, what may the the total time to complete this project.

Please, suggest how to solve this problem using any machine learning approach?

Answer (score 2):

Since the scope of answers here does not involve giving away actual answers, I will be giving some general direction to start-off.

**First Step:** You need to select which columns you want to keep in your data. This decision can be made by the business problem that you are trying to address. This step might also involve transforming some variables into things that you can relate to (e.g. cost or labor requirements).

**Second Step:** You need to normalize your input. Scale and center all of them to a range [0,1]. This is necessary for correct distance calculation.

**Third Step:** You need to decide a distance metric. That is how you want to calculate the distance(Or similarity) between the projects. Different metrics example are: euclidian, manhattan, cosine etc.

Now to start off, you can try K-means clustering. This method requires deciding in advance how many clusters you want to create. You can easily try other methods and all of them are easily available in any language(R, Python etc).

Selecting the best clustering algorithm depends heavily on your data type and domain knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Just search the most similar record. 200 records is tiny, you do not need an optimized algorithm for this.

Clustering is much harder than similarity search - fact is, most clustering algorithns *require* pairwise similarities.